# connect google spreadsheet to amazon redshift with jdbc mysql vs postgresql

Tags: jdbc, amazon-redshift

- I have an amazon redshift db that supports connecting a postgresql client with jdbc
- google apps scripts support connecting to a db with jdbc, but only with the mysql, ms sql, and oracle protocol, but not postgresql.  If I try, not surprisingly I get error:

'Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol.'

Looking at some google forums, this has been an issue for several years with no response from google.

Is there any workaround?

thanks

Comment: It's understandable that they don't want to let you upload your own JDBC driver - they don't want to run random, unknown code. While it's very frustrating that they don't offer PgJDBC I don't think you'll have many options except to convince them to add it or doing CSV exports then uploading CSV data to your scripts. Good luck, they aren't exactly noted for being responsive.

Comment: thanks, Craig.  We'll see if google gets around to this.

Comment: @Elm did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Google data studio supports Postgre so you could use it as a workaround and connect your script to your data studio data.

Answer (score 1):

I use Kloudio - a google sheets extension to get this done. I can run and schedule my redshift queries in Kloudio

Answer (score 0):

If you are using amazon redshift then you can connect it through amazon redshift client

Here are the steps:

1. Write SQL query in the redshift client and save it as a report
2. use its api key generated and report no. in the embedded link.
3. use Importdata function to google spreadsheet to import the data automatically. it will refresh by default every one hour.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give me the name of a client that generates an API Key?